# How to arrange Wordpress posts by date in a custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

on a custom wordpress theme I am developing for a client (http://garethstewart.co.uk) I have a list of Events which are a custom post type.  I want to be able to order them chronologically.  Here is the code I have to render out the dates:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'event', 'posts_per_page' => 9 );$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php $event_date = get_field('date'); // Get the event's date ?>
<?php $today = date('F j, Y'); // Get today's date ?>
<?php if ($event_date >= $today) : ?>
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="feature">
            <i class="icon inline-block mb30 fade-0-4 fa fa-calendar-o" style="font-size: 38px !important;"></i>
            <h4 class="uppercase bold"><?php the_field('date'); ?></h4>
            <h5><?php the_field('description'); ?></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your arguments:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'event', 
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key' => 'date',
        'meta_type' => 'DATE',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    )
```